# Query Optimization for IN condition

Tags: sql

I have a query using not in.

When I execute the same, it takes 24secs.

Kindly optimize the same

```
SELECT GRIRNO,grirdate 
FROM GRIRmain 
where grirno in (select grirno 
                 from grir_pass 
                 where ins_check is not null) 
order by grirdate desc
```

Comment: You claim your query uses `NOT IN` however, the query you have shown uses `IN`

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `GRIRNO`  primary key in your table then below query may perform better

```
       SELECT GRIRNO,grirdate FROM GRIRmain 
       where not exists  (select 1  from grir_pass 
       where ins_check is not null
       and grir_pass.grirno=GRIRmain.GRIRNO
                     )
         order by grirdate desc
```

From your comments it seems you need not exists

Comment: @user3698150 as you used in thats why used exists but it seems you need not exists

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your code   the IN  clause  on the subquery could be refactored  with a inner join

```
    SELECT GRIRmain.GRIRNO,GRIRmain.grirdate 
    FROM GRIRmain 
    INNER JOIN ( 
      select distinct grirno 
      from grir_pass 
      where ins_check is not null
    ) t on t.grirno = GRIRmain.grirno 
    order by grirdate desc
```

Comment: Not all `IN` conditions can be changed to a JOIN - that is a different result